# When I try to get an mysql export, it returns null for some fields which are not null in the table

Tags: mysql

I have a Mysql Database. In a huge table (which has 22000 rows) when I try to get an .SQL export file in phpmyadmin or mysqldump they return null for some fields, during in the table, they have value.
but when in phpMyAdmin in export page, I choose

```
"include column names in every INSERT statement
      Example: INSERT INTO tbl_name (col_A,col_B,col_C) VALUES (1,2,3)"
```

in "Syntax to use when inserting data:" it works correctly and adds all values for all rows.
How can I fix this issue? because I would like to get backup with mysqldump.
Thanks.

For example in the table I have something like this:

```
id | name | age | field_1 | field_2 | field_3 |
----------------------------------------------
22 | john | 35  | value_1 | value_2 | value_3 |
23 | dany | 38  | value_x | value_a | value_4 |
24 | nela | 25  | value_y | value_b | value_5 |
25 | jack | 43  | value_z | value_c | value_6 |
```

but when I use mysqldump in the generated sql it shows something like the below:

```
INSERT INTO `sample_table` (`id`, `name`, `age`, `field_1`, `field_2`, `field_3`) 

VALUES

(22 , 'john' , 35  , NULL , NULL , NULL),
(23 , 'dany' , 38  , NULL , NULL , NULL),
(24 , 'nela' , 25  , NULL , NULL , NULL),
(25 , 'jack' , 43  , NULL , NULL , NULL);
```

I use this simple mysqldump command:

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user='db_user' --password='xxx' 'db_name' > backup-full.sql
```

Comment: Give us a SELECT statement and a dumped value to show us a couple of examples of what you mean? Are you sure it's not just skipping over the null columns?

Comment: @barrycarter Sure, thank you for your comment, I edited the answer and added example.

Comment: That's strange... what command line are you using for `mysqldump`?

Comment: mysqldump --host=localhost --user='db_user' --password='xxx' 'db_name' > backup-full.sql